# JavaScript: достать данные из куска html кода записанных в переменную

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как в JavaScript из переменной содержащую html код, получить значение `value` в теге `<input>`?

Например, есть переменная, значение которой я получил после Ajax запроса:

```
var a = '<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid black"><div      class="radio_buttons"><input type="radio" name="test" value="751" checked></div></div>';
```

Мне необходимо получить значение `value` у `<input>`.
Если бы код был в теле документа я бы написал:

```
radio = document.querySelector('#test_div input[type=radio]').value;
console.log(radio );
```

Но так не годится, потому что этих данных в документе нет.

Поскольку они находятся в переменной, то я пишу:

```
radio = a.querySelector('#test_div input[type=radio]').value;
```

но возникает ошибка.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо!

Comment: Может просто вставить из переменной в DOM в скрытом виде и оттуда забрать? как вариант можно взять cheerio - https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: а _value_ Только один в этом куске текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если заранее известно, что в куске кода может быть только один инпут с атрибутом *value* то можно воспользоваться простым регулярным выражением

```js
var a = '<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid black"><div      class="radio_buttons"><input type="radio" name="test" value="751" checked></div></div>';

var val = a.match(/value="(.+?)"/)[1];
console.log(val);
```

В противном случае можно создать элемент и присвоить ему *innerHTML*, и затем уже искать в нем

```js
var a = '<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid black"><div      class="radio_buttons"><input type="radio" name="test" value="751" checked></div></div>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = a;

var radio = div.querySelector('#test_div input[type=radio]').value;
console.log(radio);
```

Либо воспользоваться [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var a = '<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid black"><div      class="radio_buttons"><input type="radio" name="test" value="751" checked></div></div>';

var parser = new DOMParser();

var radio = parser.parseFromString(a, 'text/html').querySelector('#test_div input[type=radio]').value;
console.log(radio);
```